# Android- Stop Telephony Manager service

Tags: android

Actually i am new to android developer and i am having a stop button in my activity class and i want to stop the telephony service so that it will not record call after stop button is clicked but it is not stoping service and itis recording the call. 
Please help to resolve the problem

My Activity class is

```
package com.jain.callrecorderdemo;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
Button startbtn, stopbtn;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    startbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startbtnid);
    stopbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stopbtnid);
    startbtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CallRecordingService.class);
            startService(in);

        }
    });
    stopbtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CallRecordingService.class);
            stopService(in);

        }
    });
}
}
```

My CallREcorder Service

```
package com.jain.callrecorderdemo;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager.OnActivityStopListener;
import android.telephony.PhoneStateListener;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class CallRecordingService extends Service{

TelephonyManager tm;
MediaRecorder mr;
static int x=0;
int id;
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
} 

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    id=startId;
    tm=(TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    tm.listen(new MyPhoneListener(), PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}
@Override
public void onDestroy() {

Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Call Recorder off", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    super.onDestroy();
}


class MyPhoneListener extends PhoneStateListener
{
    @Override
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
        super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
        switch (state) {
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "IDLE", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            try {
                mr.release();   
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            break;

        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Ringing", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;

        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "OFFHOOK", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            try {
                mr=new MediaRecorder();
                mr.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
                mr.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
                mr.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.DEFAULT);
                File mysdpath=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                File mydir=new File(mysdpath,"Recording_folder");
                if(mydir.exists()==false)
                {
                    mydir.mkdir();
                }
                String filepath=mydir.getAbsolutePath()+"/recorderfile"+(x++)+".mp3";
                mr.setOutputFile(filepath);
                mr.prepare();
                mr.start();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Recording started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            break;
        }
    }
}
}
```

My Manifest file is

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.jain.callrecorderdemo"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="7"
    android:targetSdkVersion="23" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity android:name="MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <service android:name="CallRecordingService"></service>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Is there something you have writteen in the manifest file. Please post your manifest file.

Comment: i have added manifest also..

Answer (score 0):

You can use LISTEN_NONE as parameter to stop listening for updates.

```
telephonymanager.listen(phoneStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_NONE );
```

Hope this will help you, Thanks.